# C++ mockup server returing JSON not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I very much want to create a mockup server that gives me (for now) hard-coded results to JSON queries.  Right now I'm simply returning properly formatted JSON text from the server.

However, in my code below, I get the following from the error function:

Error in LoadingPage status: error   Response text= undefined   Error was undefined

I'm wondering if this is because of my server or if there's something wrong with the code on the client side.  What do you think?

Thanks a lot!
Mike

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    LoadingPage();
} );

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function LoadingPage()
{
    alert("In LoadingPage");

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "localhost",
            success: function(result)
                {                       
                  alert('poopoo');
                },
            error: function(xhr, status, error)
                {
                  alert("Error in LoadingPage status: " + status + "   Response text= "+xhr.responseText + "   Error was " + error.statusText);
                },


            async:true
            });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request looks good, make sure the response is well formed. As per http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html
a proper response would look like this, at a minimum:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
\r\n
<content goes here>
```

Comment: I just realized- my server is not being called at all from the ajax call.  If I go to a browser and go to localhost, it returns my JSON text in the browser.  Any idea why this is not working from ajax?